# not able to create pipeline in microsoft azure using python(2.0) getting the following error

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

Here is my main function. I am getting the following error shown in the snapshot below.

```
def main():

    # Azure subscription ID
    subscription_id = ''

    # This program creates this resource group. If it's an existing resource group, comment out the code that creates the resource group
    rg_name = ''

    # The data factory name. It must be globally unique.
    df_name = ''        

    # Specify your Active Directory client ID, client secret, and tenant ID
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='', secret='', tenant='')
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    adf_client = DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

    rg_params = {'location':'eastus'}
    df_params = {'location':'eastus'}

    # create the resource group
    # comment out if the resource group already exits
    #resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(rg_name, rg_params)

    # Create a data factory
    #df_resource = Factory(location='eastus')
    #df = adf_client.factories.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, df_resource)
    #print_item(df)
    #while df.provisioning_state != 'Succeeded':
    #    df = adf_client.factories.get(rg_name, df_name)
    #    time.sleep(1)

    # Create an Azure Storage linked service
    ls_name = ''

    # Specify the name and key of your Azure Storage account
    storage_string = SecureString('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=;AccountKey=;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')
    ls_azure_storage = AzureStorageLinkedService(connection_string=storage_string)
    ls = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ls_name, ls_azure_storage)
    print_item(ls)

    # Create an Azure blob dataset (input)
    ds_name = ''
    ds_ls = LinkedServiceReference(ls_name)
    blob_path= ''
    blob_filename = ''
    ds_azure_blob= AzureBlobDataset(ds_ls, folder_path=blob_path, file_name = blob_filename)
    ds = adf_client.datasets.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ds_name, ds_azure_blob)
    print_item(ds)

    # Create an Azure blob dataset (output)
    dsOut_name = ''
    output_blobpath = ''
    dsOut_azure_blob = AzureBlobDataset(ds_ls, folder_path=output_blobpath)
    dsOut = adf_client.datasets.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, dsOut_name, dsOut_azure_blob)
    print_item(dsOut)

    # Create a copy activity
    act_name =  ''
    blob_source = BlobSource()
    blob_sink = BlobSink()
    dsin_ref = DatasetReference(ds_name)
    dsOut_ref = DatasetReference(dsOut_name)
    copy_activity = CopyActivity(act_name,inputs=[dsin_ref], outputs=[dsOut_ref], source=blob_source, sink=blob_sink)

    # Create a pipeline with the copy activity
    p_name =  ''
    params_for_pipeline = {}
    p_obj = PipelineResource(activities=[copy_activity], parameters=params_for_pipeline)
    p = adf_client.pipelines.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, p_name, p_obj)
    print_item(p)

    # Create a pipeline run
    run_response = adf_client.pipelines.create_run(rg_name, df_name, p_name,
        {
        }
    )

    # Monitor the pipeilne run
    time.sleep(30)
    pipeline_run = adf_client.pipeline_runs.get(rg_name, df_name, run_response.run_id)
    print("\n\tPipeline run status: {}".format(pipeline_run.status))
    activity_runs_paged = list(adf_client.activity_runs.list_by_pipeline_run(rg_name, df_name, pipeline_run.run_id, datetime.now() - timedelta(1),  datetime.now() + timedelta(1)))
    print_activity_run_details(activity_runs_paged[0])
```

---

i am getting the following error:-
ErrorResponseException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 main()

in main()
     37 
     38     ls_azure_storage = AzureStorageLinkedService(connection_string=storage_string)
---> 39     ls = adf_client.linked_services.create_or_update(rg_name, df_name, ls_name, ls_azure_storage)
     40     print_item(ls)
     41

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/azure/mgmt/datafactory/operations/linked_services_operations.pyc in create_or_update(self, resource_group_name, factory_name, linked_service_name, properties, if_match, custom_headers, raw, **operation_config)
    170 
    171         if response.status_code not in [200]:
--> 172             raise models.ErrorResponseException(self._deserialize, response)
    173 
    174         deserialized = None

ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

[image]

Comment: Seems you don’t have permission. Do you have write permission of that subscription?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add the error as a text message to your question instead of the image? Just copy the error message out of your notebook, indent it by four spaces and add it to your question using the edit button. This makes your question easier to find both for people who might help you as well as people having the same problem.

Comment: hi Fang Liu i have added the error please try to help its urgent

Answer (score 0):

Forbidden generally means you don’t have permission. Could you check if you have the write permission of that data factory?

Are you using ADF v1 or v2?
Did you tried create a pipeline in UI since that is an easy way to verify your permission?